# ion-datetime month and day names can't be defined globally

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

According to the ionic documentation you can configure the months and day names used by the `ion-datetime` globally. Sadly I haven't been able to find a way and the only answer by the ionic team on this issue is on github and its not very helpful (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/15374)

I need this because in ionic 3 this was possible by setting the values on the config like this

```js
this.config.set('monthNames', months);
this.config.set('monthShortNames', monthsShort);
this.config.set('dayNames', weekdays);
this.config.set('dayShortNames', weekdaysShort);
```

Or as part of the `IonicModule.forRoot` configuration (Second parameter)

Answer (score 0):

To work around this issue, I have created an angular directive with the `ion-datetime` as selector. I inject the `IonDatetime` in combination with the `Self` decorator to get hold of the instance of the `ion-datetime` component. Once I have done so I can simply set the values of

- dayNames
- dayShortNames
- monthNames
- monthShortNames

The nice thing about this solution is that it works globally, and you don't have to provide the component with your localisation values everytime you use it. In my case I save the localisation values in a provider but you can get yours from anywhere else.

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { IonDatetime } from '@ionic/angular';
import { MomentProvider } from 'src/app/services/moment/moment';
import { ILoggable, Logger } from 'src/app/shared/decorators/logger';

/**
 * Whenever thes a ion-datetime, we want to edit its localisation
 */
@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-datetime',
})
export class IonDateTimeDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(@Self() private dateTime: IonDatetime, private $moment: MomentProvider) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dateTime.dayNames = this.$moment.ionDateTimeLocalisation.dayNames;
    this.dateTime.dayShortNames = this.$moment.ionDateTimeLocalisation.dayShortNames;
    this.dateTime.monthNames = this.$moment.ionDateTimeLocalisation.monthNames;
    this.dateTime.monthShortNames = this.$moment.ionDateTimeLocalisation.monthShortNames;
  }

}
```